# PostgreSQL inserting multiple tables and rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have 2 structs one Company the other Service. They have a `has-many` relationship company to service. I'm trying to write an SQL query that will insert a company and multiple services attached to that company in one query.

RAW SQL:

```
WITH company AS ( INSERT INTO companies(id, name) VALUES('1', 'acme') RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO services(id, company_id, name) VALUES
('1', (select company.id from company), 'cool service'),
('2', (select company.id from company), 'cooler service');
```

I'm trying to imitate this using go's sql package. This is my attempt thus far: I've added the structs at the top just for clarity

```
c := &Company{
    ID: uuid.NewV4().String(),
    Name: "test comp",
}

s := []*Service{
    &Service{
        ID: uuid.NewV4().String(),
        CompanyID: c.ID,
        Name: "test svc",
    },
}

c.Service = s

values := []interface{}{
    c.ID,
    c.Name,
}

q := `
    WITH company as (INSERT INTO companies(id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)) INSERT INTO services(id, company_id, name) VALUES
`

for _, row := range c.Services {
    q += "($1, $2, $3),"
    values = append(values, row.ID, row.CompanyID)
}

q = strings.TrimSuffix(q, ",")

stmt, err := s.DB.Prepare(q)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if _, err := stmt.Exec(values...); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I'm not sure how else to go about this but with this method I get this error:

```
ERROR #08P01 bind message supplies 5 parameters, but prepared statement "1" requires 3
```

Which makes sense I'm passing 5 parameters to exec when prepared statement "1" which I'm guessing is the second one only requires 3. But how can I perform my query without having to split it up into more than 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as your error message says, your SQL statement only uses 3 bind variables:

```
   WITH company as (INSERT INTO companies(id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)) INSERT INTO services(id, company_id, name) VALUES
```

and:

```
    q += "($1, $2, $3),"
```

You're simply repeating `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` for each of your rows.  So your constructed query will look something like:

```
WITH company as (INSERT INTO companies(id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)) INSERT INTO services(id, company_id, name) VALUES
($1, $2, $3),($1, $2, $3),($1, $2, $3),($1, $2, $3),
```

Clearly that's not what you want.  You need to increment your bind variable numbering with each iteration through the loop.

My approach would probably be something like:

```
var i int = 3
for _, row := range c.Services {
    q += fmt.Sprintf("($%d, $%d, $%d),", i, i+1, i+2)
    values = append(values, row.ID, row.CompanyID)
    i += 3
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be incrementing per iteration of the for loop it would be for each binding variable used.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Well, my approach would be to increment a variable by 3 every time through the loop. If you prefer three separate iterations, that could work just as well. Take your pick.

Comment: I'm gonna mark your answer as correct since you answered my question. This whole method though feels very smelly. Is there a better way to go about this? Like overall not just trying to fix my hacky method?

Comment: Some backend drivers support using `?`, or even named parameters. But unfortunately, the `pq` driver does not appear to support this. Another alternative might be to use the [sqlx](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/lib/deps/request-browser.js) library, which adds named parameter support on top of the `sql` package, so it works with any backend. Whether that would actually be easier for you, I'm not sure.